# Would it be okay to top up manual transmission fluid (GearOil) when engine is hot

Tags: transmission, transmission-fluid, gear-oil, fluid-level

Title Pretty much explains the question, would it be okay to do this when the engine is hot. the gearbox would also be hot obviously.

Comment: What make/model/engine are you wondering about? The reason I ask is, depending on the vehicle, the answer may be different.

Comment: As @Paulster says we need to know the vehicle as some are topped up with engine running after cycling through the gears either hot or cold, others when engine not running and all variations between.

Comment: @SolarMike - The OP is asking about a manual transmission ... what you are describing is for an automatic. Running through the gears on a manual won't change a thing.

Comment: My apologies, it's a 2007 ford fiesta.

Comment: Apologies for mis-reading... If it is a mk6 then this link gives lots of info : http://www.fordownersclub.com/forums/topic/12648-fiesta-mk6-gearbox-filler/

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

It's sort of like an oil change after driving around a bit. The only real concern is burning yourself.

Of course, this being the transmission, you are less likely to burn yourself because "hot" for a manual transmission isn't really that hot. The oil is subjected to extremely high pressures (between gear teeth) but nothing that's combusting.

Just remember to always remove the fill port bolt before the drain plug if you decide to drain and refill. I do also wonder why you need to "top up" MTF... It's normally a sealed system.

Comment: Very good points, all. +1.